# Fetch record from table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble fetching data from my table with the following.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email,password) VALUES (:email,:password)";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
  $stmt->execute();

if(!$query){
    echo 'Whoops, something went wrong!';
} else {
    while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
        echo $r['surname']; 
    }
};
```

Can anybody see where im going wrong? By not working, nothing is output to my browser

Comment: is error cheking and display on?

Comment: You are running conditional on $query which is just a string I think you want to check for example if $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query) returns properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up insert and select syntax.

Your select syntax should be something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email AND password=:password";
```

Apart from that you should take a look around on SO and search for `secure password hashing` as `md5` is not secure.

Comment: @Liam You should add error handling to your database calls, see for example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a valid SQL query. `VALUES()` is only used with `UPDATE` statements.

Try to use statement

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password =:password
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email,password) VALUES (:email,:password)
```

needs to be

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password
```

I would also encourage you to use a SALT value with your password to defend against rainbow table attacks.

Answer (score -1):

As the above users noticed, the problem was at the SQL query.
In order to catch and display SQL errors you should use a try catch statement in the future.

```
try {
  /*Code to access database with PDO*/
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```